# draggable is being dropped in different location than droppable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm creating a drag and drop candlestick. I have a div with id droppable but when I drag the draggable div the droppable registers when the draggable div isn't in the right position.

[image: Droppable being registered when the candle is in that position]

Droppable being registered when the candle is in the position as can be seen in image. Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/naomilea/pen/QGmdrm)

Relevant code

Drop here

```
<div id="lighting" class="ui-widget-content">
    <div id="shamash"></div>
    <div id="flame"></div>
</div>
$(function() {
    $("#lighting").draggable({ revert: "invalid" });
    $(".flame").hide();
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(".flame").show();

        }
    });
});
```

Could this have to do with position: absolute or is there another explination to this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? I can't get the problem

Comment: I want the .flame to show when the #lighting is dropped in #droppable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using nested `div` in `html` you can use `css` and `handle` property of `draggable` plugin. use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pandeyvishal1986/f5eyhda1/3/#&togetherjs=3GOujvwIj3):

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
    $("#flame").draggable({revert:"invalid",cursor: "move",handle:"#shamash" });
    $(".flame").hide();
    $("#droppable").droppable({
    greedy:true,
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(".flame").show();

        }
    });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="flame">
      <div id="shamash"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#shamash {
    height: 60px;
    //right: 390px;
    //top: 240px;
    position: relative;
    background-color:white;
    right: 0px;
    top: 20px;
}

#flame {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 15px;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 80px 80px 10px 10px;
    right: 390px;
    top: 220px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 1px yellow;
}
```